# Animation don't work in Dialog

Tags: android, android-animation, android-alertdialog

When i start my App a dialog comes and in this dialog i want an animation! But the animation (a wizard who speaks) doesn't work.
This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences mPrefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Context mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
    mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", 0);        

    if(getFirstRun()) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        setRan();
        dialog.show();
    }
}

public boolean getFirstRun() {
    return mPrefs.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
}

public void setRan() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
    edit.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
    edit.apply();
}
}
```

and this is my Main2Activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

    img.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground()).start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Can someone help me how I can fix the problem?

Comment: why `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);`?? Newbie ??

Comment: What should be otherwise purely pro?

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
   dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
```

left_slide.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
android:duration="500" />
```

right_slide.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500"
android:fromXDelta="0"
android:toXDelta="100%p" />
```

in style file.
DilaogAnimation

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/left_slide</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/right_slide</item>
</style>
```